# Server.Transfer and Getlastwritetime

Tags: asp.net, server.transfer

I'm using asp.net 3.0.

I have Page A doing a Server.Transfer to Page B.

On both page A and Page B I'm want to be able to use System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(MapPath(Page.Request.Path.ToString())) in order to display the last modified date at the top of each file.

This works well on page A, but when I use Server.Transfer to page B,  Page.Request.Path still refers to Page A as opposed to Page B.

Is there any way around this without changing from Server.Transfer to Response.Redirect (Server.Transfer is important for my other sections of code on both pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(MapPath(Page.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath))
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.  Thanks a million, I was scratching my  head on this for quite a while.